# Trying to create dataframes from list using pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to define a function that takes a list of stock tickers and creates a dataframe for each ticker with the proper data from yahoo finance.

First the function takes a *arg.

Once passed a ticker/list-of-tickers, the function loops through the list.

For each ticker the function calls pandas_data readers and gets data on the specific ticker.

That data is stored in a dataframe named "df" + str(ticker)

I have:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd


def Finance1(*args):
    for arg in args: 
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(arg)
        global df'arg'
        df'arg' = df

x = "IBM"
y = "XOM"        
list = [x, y]        

Finance1(*list)
```

Can't seem to dynamically create dataframes named for the ticker atm in the loop/ also dynamically create local variabels. Thanks in advance.

Off comment below made changes below still not getting the desired output.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {}
def Finance1(*args):
    for arg in args:
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(arg)
        dict1[arg] = df
        return dict1


x = "IBM"
y = "XOM"        
list = [x, y]        

Finance1(*list)
```

Second Edit

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd

def Finance1(*args):
    dict1 = {}
    for arg in args:
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(arg)
        return dict1
        dict1[arg] = df



x = "IBM"
y = "XOM"        
list1 = [x, y]        

results = Finance1(*list)
```

Final and now Working:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd

def Finance1(*args):
    dict1 = {}
    for arg in args:
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(arg)
        dict1[arg] = df
    return dict1


x = "IBM"
y = "XOM"        
list1 = [x, y]        

results = Finance1(*list1)
```

Comment: `global df'arg'`: are you trying to create a variable dfXYZ (if arg=XYZ)?  I'm pretty sure you can't create dynamic variable name like that.  consider creating an empty dictionary inside your function and in the loop save the df to `dict[arg]=df` then return the dict at the end of the function. That gets rid of the use of global too.

Comment: @user1558604 made your edit but still not getting exactly what i'm looking for. Did I implement correctly. Thanks!

Comment: put `dict`={}` outside of the for loop (but still inside the function). Also, move `return dict1` up one level. Right now you are emptying the dictionary each time, and stopping the function after one loop (that is what return does).

Comment: Also, you'll need to run your function with something like `result = Finance1(*list)` in order to recover the results

Comment: And finally, you should name a variable list. It is a protected name

Comment: close... the return statement should be the last thing the function should run.  That means it should be the last line, and outside of the for loop.  Thus one line down from your second edit, and in line with `for` and `dict1`. Also, don't forget to change your function call to `*list1` now that you changed your variable name.

Comment: Got it thanks you are the best!!!!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  I try to help lead people to the answer when I can rather than just give it straight up. I don't do any formal tutoring, but I am trying to help get better at explaining things as I often need to do that for my job. I am confident that you have figured this all out, but I am going to leave this here for reference if you need it. https://repl.it/repls/DelightfulBrilliantMathematics I added comments to the lines that we changed to explain what they do.

Comment: Thanks again @user1558604 if you could upvote the question that would be great, also if you move your comment to an answer i'll give it a check